# C++ write to mysql databasein utf8 characters?

Tags: c++, mysql, utf-8

I want to send data to a Mysql database, with the following code:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "my_global.h"
#include "mysql.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "libmysql")
#pragma comment(lib, "mysqlclient")
using namespace std;

MYSQL *connection, mysql;
MYSQL_RES *result;
MYSQL_ROW row;
int query_state;

int main() 
{mysql_init(&mysql);
//connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"host","user","password","database",0,0,0);
connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost","testc++","mypassword","testc++",0,0,0);
if (connection == NULL) 
cout << mysql_error(&mysql) << endl;
else
cout << "connection established" << endl;
mysql_query(connection, "CREATE TABLE writers(name VARCHAR(25))");

mysql_query(connection, "INSERT INTO writers VALUES('攻殻機動隊')");
mysql_query(connection, "INSERT INTO writers VALUES('ブルージェンダー')");
mysql_query(connection, "INSERT INTO writers VALUES('Honore de Balzac')");
mysql_query(connection, "INSERT INTO writers VALUES('Lion Feuchtwanger')");
mysql_query(connection, "INSERT INTO writers VALUES('Emile Zola')");
query_state = mysql_query(connection, "select user_count()");
if (query_state !=0) {
cout << mysql_error(connection) << endl;


mysql_close(connection);

cin.get();
// This code disconnects the mysql connection.
mysql_free_result(result);
mysql_close(connection);
return 1;
}
```

The issue I am having is that the Japanese icons get saved as ???? instead of ブルージェンダー
How would I fix this?
I'm using visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the character encoding in the mysql field to be UTF8, or is it latin1, which does not support international characters.

you can set the field encoding like this:

`"CREATE TABLE writers(name VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)"`

---

EDIT 1

If that is not the solution, this could be a visual studio issue, which can be solved like this:

`wchar_t query_string = L"INSERT INTO writers VALUES('攻殻機動隊')";`

you will need to convert '攻殻機動隊' into a unicode string using a converter such as [this one here](http://www.rishida.net/tools/conversion/)

I picked the UTF=8 ones but I have no way of knowing if these are correct or how to use them, you'll need to find out which one is the correct sequence by trail and error im afraid.

To make your life easier here is a link to a [library](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) which might be able to do all this for you.

[source is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zkb5h07%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: What do you mean by mysql field?
In phpmyadmin the databse is set to: utf8_general_ci

Comment: the `varchar` fields can be set to a certain character encoding, my last project had the same problem as yours but they were all set to latin1, which was the problem. I forget how to do it however and don't have a test rig set up :(.

Comment: @gijs007: `utf8_general_ci` is a **collation** not an encoding. Make sure that column has `utf8` encoding and that the connection itself is `utf8` encoded (`SET NAMES utf8;`).

Comment: in your first statment where you create the table, here ill add it to the asnwer

Comment: I did that but its still putting ??? in my database.

I also get some errors from visual studio: 1>Source1.cpp(25): warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u30FC' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)

Comment: ahh i see what is happening, this is a visual studio issue, i'll post a solution now.